# Player not moving in 2D Game

Tags: java, keylistener

I can not seem to get my player to move when certain keys are pressed. I did some debugging and placed a `System.out.print("Pressed);` in the if statements that check if a key is pressed and it prints out the message every time I press the key, they player just is not moving. Can someone help!

here is the InputHandler class

```
public class InputHandler implements KeyListener {

    public InputHandler(Game game) {
        game.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public class Key {
        private boolean pressed = false;

        public void toggle(boolean isPressed) {
            pressed = isPressed;
        }

        public boolean isPressed() {
            return pressed;
        }
    }

    // public List<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>();
    public Key up = new Key();
    public Key down = new Key();
    public Key left = new Key();
    public Key right = new Key();

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void toggleKey(int keyCode, boolean isPressed) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            up.toggle(isPressed);
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            down.toggle(isPressed);
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            left.toggle(isPressed);
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            right.toggle(isPressed);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Player class

```
public class Player extends Mob {

    private InputHandler input;
    private int r = 10;

    public Player(int x, int y, int speed, InputHandler input) {
        super("Player", x, y, 1);
        this.input = input;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean hasCollided(int dx, int dy) {
        return false;
    }

    public void update() {
        int dx = 0;
        int dy = 0;

        if (input.up.isPressed()) {
            dy--;
        } else if (input.down.isPressed()) {
            dy++;
        } else if (input.left.isPressed()) {
            dx--;
        } else if (input.right.isPressed()) {
            dx++;
        }

        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
            move(dx, dy);
            isMoving = true;
        } else {
            isMoving = false;
        }

        if (x < r)
            x = r;
        if (y < r)
            y = r;
        if (x > Game.WIDTH - r)
            x = Game.WIDTH - r;
        if (y > Game.HEIGHT - r)
            y = Game.HEIGHT - r;
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x - r, y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);

        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawOval(x - r, y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    }
}
```

and here is the Mob class that has the `move()` method in it

```
    public Mob(String name, int x, int y, int speed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void move(int dx, int dy) {
        if (dx != 0 && dy != 0) {
            move(dx, 0);
            move(dy, 0);
            numSteps--;
            return;
        }
        numSteps++;

        if (!hasCollided(dx, dy)) {
            if (dy < 0)
                movingDir = 0;
            if (dy > 0)
                movingDir = 1;
            if (dx < 0)
                movingDir = 2;
            if (dx > 0)
                movingDir = 3;

            x += dx * speed;
            y += dy * speed;
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean hasCollided(int dx, int dy);

    public String getName() {
        return _name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where is the render method inside the Player class called? Have you overridded paint(Graphics) or paintComponent(Graphics) somewhere?

Turns out the JFrame didn't have focus. Once it was in focus the code worked beautifully.

Comment: This is not an answer. A comment would be more suitiable.

Comment: I would have but I don't have the ability to post comments as I only have 38 points :(

Comment: @ZebBarnett the update occurs in the game loop in the Game classes update and render methods

Comment: @zachstarnes Ahh, makes sense. After another look I'm quite confused about a piece of your move method in the Mob class. It seems that you have a recursive situation going on but you're passing dy into the dx spot in the second recursive call. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ZebBarnett no it was not intentional and i changed it. But still no motion.

Comment: @zachstarnes Comment out your border checking code in Player.update() and see what happens.

Comment: @ZebBarnett nothing happens now if i type the `System.out.print("Pressed")` in the if statements checking the the kety is pressed nothing prints out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43011/discussion-between-zachstarnes-and-zeb-barnett)

Answer (score 1):

This code has all sorts of problems, but the most pressing seems to be that there is refrences to both _x and x. Choose one and make all the methods use that one. This may help, but honestly it is hard to tell exactly what to fix, maybe start with something simpler?

Answer (score 0):

I found one error with your code for move. You call `move(dx, 0)` and `move(dy, 0)` inside an if statement, if **both** of them are not 0. In the ensuing recursion, they are both 0 and nothing is done. Instead, change the `&&` to a `||`

```
public void move(int dx, int dy) {
        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
            move(dx, 0);
            move(dy, 0);
            numSteps--;
            return;
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: I changed the operators as you stated but the player still does not move :(

Comment: ok, I haven't really looked at the code.  but, if dx means delta x, why are you doing an if?  just move delta x.  collide should throw an error, perhaps.

Comment: @Bucco the point of the if is so that if two keys are pressed it handles them one at a time so that the player does not move at double to speed

Comment: @zachstarnes I have a question - what are x and y inside the Mob class? I see that you have a _x and a _y but at the bottom of the move method I don't understand what the x,y are.

Comment: @Bucco x and y are the starting points of the mob when it is created so as it stands the player starts in the middle of the screen and the `move()` method changes that x and y

Answer (score 0):

There's so much code here that it's really too much for a single question.

A better approach would be to go ahead and make each class smaller.  Specifically, don't error check for walls.  Just move the mob/whatever around.  If there's a problem, then the game(?) will throw an error...

In general, I would say that this approach is overly concerned with "what if?" problems rather than the basics of maneuverings a 2d dungeon with x,y coordinate system.

(Just to confuse matters, what if it was in polar coordinates!? Anyhow...)

After getting your code to run, I went ahead and put it on github for you:

https://github.com/THUFIR/Game2D/tree/master/src/genericGame

Feel free to fork it, please do.  Git, or any version control, can really help out when your code was working, but something broke...

Here's the output, very simple:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Game2D$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Game2D$ java -jar dist/Game2D.jar 
x   1   y   1
x   4   y   6
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/Game2D$
```

driver:

```
package genericGame;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player(0, 0, 0);
        player.move(1, 1);
        out.println(player);
        player.move(3, 5);
        out.println(player);
    }
}
```

and player:

```
package genericGame;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Player extends Mob {

    private int r = 10;

    public Player(int x, int y, int speed) {
        super("Player", x, y);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean hasCollided(int dx, int dy) {
        return false;
    }

    public void update() {
        int dx = 0;
        int dy = 0;

        if (input.up.isPressed()) {
            dy--;
        } else if (input.down.isPressed()) {
            dy++;
        } else if (input.left.isPressed()) {
            dx--;
        } else if (input.right.isPressed()) {
            dx++;
        }

        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
            move(dx, dy);
            isMoving = true;
        } else {
            isMoving = false;
        }

        if (x < r) {
            x = r;
        }
        if (y < r) {
            y = r;
        }
        if (x > Game.WIDTH - r) {
            x = Game.WIDTH - r;
        }
        if (y > Game.HEIGHT - r) {
            y = Game.HEIGHT - r;
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x - r, y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);

        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawOval(x - r, y - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.  Please learn git.

I'll read the other answers to see better solutions, I just hit it with a hammer until it compiled.  The naming conventions, organization, and access levels to methods, classes and fields are all, well, let's say, opportunities for improvement.